# Retrieve value of desired index only

Tags: jquery

I have select box. I m retrieving value on change function. Similiarly I am getting json having index similar to retrieved id. I want to retrieve index of json with similar retrieved id. How's this possible in jQuery.

2
    Object { Reservation={...}, Guest={...}, Room={...}}

Guest
    Object { id="8", first_name="Pramod", last_name="Kumar"}

Reservation
    Object { id="7", reservation_id=null}

Room
    Object { room_no="123", id="2"}

15
    Object { Reservation={...}, Guest={...}, Room={...}}

Guest
    Object { id="6", first_name="Vinod", last_name="Kumar"}

Reservation
    Object { id="5", reservation_id=null}

Room
    Object { room_no="203", id="15"}

Comment: Like the index of element number two above? (In other words, the index value `2`?)

Comment: This code doesn't look like JavaScript. Is it PHP, or is it another language?

Comment: Let me maniuplate question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have encoded this array into JSON, and pass it to your javascript, then you will decode the JSON into a javascript object using JSON.parse() or jQuery.parseJSON().

Then, once it's a javascript object, you can look up values as you would any other object:

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData);
var reservationData = data['15'];
var roomData = reservationData.room;
var roomNumber = roomData.room_num;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$.each( json_obj, function( key, value ) {
   /**Say like you want value for key: 2 **/
    if(key ==2){
       /*** Do something ***/
    }
});
```

Comment: Or for particular index, I guess this would work:
**json_object.key** i.e. **json_object.2** would work, not sure but try this.